# What exactly does `(void)SomeBaseClass;` do?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I came across the following piece of code inside UE.

```cpp
template <typename OtherClassType>
FORCEINLINE bool IsA( OtherClassType SomeBase ) const
{
    // We have a cyclic dependency between UObjectBaseUtility and UClass,
    // so we use a template to allow inlining of something we haven't yet seen, because it delays compilation until the function is called.

    // 'static_assert' that this thing is actually a UClass pointer or convertible to it.
    const UClass* SomeBaseClass = SomeBase;
    (void)SomeBaseClass;
    checkfSlow(SomeBaseClass, TEXT("IsA(NULL) cannot yield meaningful results"));

    const UClass* ThisClass = GetClass();

    // Stop the compiler doing some unnecessary branching for nullptr checks
    UE_ASSUME(SomeBaseClass);
    UE_ASSUME(ThisClass);

    return IsChildOfWorkaround(ThisClass, SomeBaseClass);
}
```

I cannot understand what `(void)SomeBaseClass;` does.

Comment: typically it is used to silence a "not used variable" warning. Though if thats the reason in this code is unclear, because the variable is used

Comment: Basically, it gets rid of "unused variable" warning. But I don't see any reason to use cast to `void` here, `SomeBaseClass` is used three times, shouldn't generate any warnings.

Comment: It might have been generated by some kind of template, and then not removed when an actual implementation was written.